# Does imshow() have something to do with label->setPixmap()?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qt5

Here is a piece of code I written.

```
image = Mat2QImage(frame2Copy);
ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image).scaled(ui->label->width(),ui->label->height(),Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
imshow("frame2Copy", frame2Copy);
```

You can see that I want to translate a frame(cv::Mat) into an QImage, and then display it in a QLabel. The problem is that I can not comment the last line code:

```
imshow("frame2Copy", frame2Copy);
```

If this line of code is commented, the program will crashed. I do not need the frame to show in another new opened window since I have displayed it in a QLabel. However, I cannot remove this code. I can't figure out why. Can someone help me? Thanks very much.

Comment: Are you sure that this line is the one causing the crash. Are you trying to access the frame in later code ?

Comment: I find it strange that the window is blocked when you comment the imshow line, how are you getting frame2Copy?

Comment: does setPixmap allocate memory? Maybe the mat memory is deallocated if not used in imshow or sth.?

Comment: can you try: image = Mat2QImage(frame2Copy.clone ()); ?

Comment: what's the error message of the crash?

Comment: Can you kindly add the crash log?
imshow("frame2Copy", frame2Copy); should have no impact on the execution of the program ( sounds really weird! )

Comment: Thank you all. I am new to Qt and OpenCV and there are a lot of things that I am not familiar with. It seems that I implemented the code in a wrong way, and it's OK now. I can not understand why and I can not precisely describe the question above. But still thank you all.